# imagemagick arranging picture in a center

Tags: imagemagick

I have several images with different sizes.
1.jpg
2.jpg
3.jpg

I need to arrange them on 1 layout in the following order:
1st image in the top-left corner
2nd in the middle
3rd in the middle
(as in the example: http://postimg.org/image/4wcf5l0gl/ )

I try smth like:
montage 1.jpg 2.jpg 3.jpg -mode concatenate -tile 1x3 out.jpg
but 2nd and 3rd appear on the left side.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this with the `convert` program by a sequence of `-append` operations.  In the simplest case:

```
convert 1.jpg 2.jpg -append 3.jpg -gravity center -append out.jpg
```

Note that order of operations goes from left to right with convert.  I load two images, and append them together.  Then I load image #3 and change the `-gravity` setting to `center`, to perform a centered append (instead of a "left justified" one).  Last is the output filename.

You can add the text at the top by generating a label and putting a horizontal append (`+append`) in its proper place in the sequence:

```
convert 1.jpg label:'text from file-name' +append 2.jpg -append 3.jpg -gravity center -append out.jpg
```

To pad the images with space around them, use `-border` on each individual image before appending.  You can use grouping parentheses to limit the effect of any operation to only certain images*:

```
convert 1.jpg label:'text from file-name' -bordercolor white -border 10 +append \( 2.jpg -border 10 \) -append \( 3.jpg -border 10 \) -gravity center -append out.jpg
```

You can get more and more elaborate from here.  Just remember that order of operations proceeds from left to right, and operations can be limited to certain images by use of grouping parentheses.

*footnote: The syntax of the commands above assume a typical unix/linux shell environment.  The syntax will have to be adapted if you are using some other environment.

Comment: Thanks much! What if I need to make 1st pic circled? I mean to cut corners and make it circle-shaped? Are there any easy way to do this?

Comment: The basic technique is to create a mask of the shape that you want, and use image composition to clip the image to the shape in the mask.  You can find examples here: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/#rounded